# How to fix "no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values" error in r?

Tags: r, glm

I am conducting a register based study and would like to estimate Risk Differences using the GLM function. The unadjusted analysis goes perfect, but when I add multiple x-variables in order to adjust for them I get the error

> "Error: No valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply
>   starting values".

The code that I am running looks like this:

```
glm(formula = as.numeric(cancer_pos) ~ as.factor(income) + as.factor(sex) + as.factor(age) + as.factor(country) + as.factor(education), data = df, family = binomial(link = "identity")
```

If I exclude fx. as.factor(country) and as.factor(education) it works, however, I would like to adjust for these variables as well. So how do I determine the starting values for this function? Or is it not possible to get risk difference estimates through identity link when including so many variables?

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like your data is not sufficient to support such a complex model? I suspect you have, e.g., many countries. The usual advice would then be to make country a random effect in a GLMM. Btw., why do you litter your formula with as.*? Your data should be the correct class in the data.frame.

Comment: There is actually only three categories in the country variable and five in the variables for age and education - but should that be an issue?

Comment: Also you are right - the as.factor() does not change the estimates so it is not nessecary

Comment: I think this is pretty off-topic here as it's probably a statistics issue. You might get better help if you approach it like that instead of as a programming problem. Then it would be on-topic for stats.stackexchange.com but you would need to describe and illustrate your data in more detail.

Comment: Please delete this question here since you have posted it on Cross Validated now.